# how do i get variables in my public static void to work with my public void

Tags: java, list, methods

I'm trying to get a random output of `lookingToGetGearedUp` (being a List of Strings) to be available in the `mc.player.sendChatMessage` method.

I might want to expand what is inside `randomWorderer` in the future by putting other lists inside the method. I'd like to keep the two methods separate because I'm trying to make this as easy to read as possible for my own reading and maybe just as general practice of good coding principles.

I'm learning so I don't really know how methods work in Java (I'm not even sure if that's what you call them (I mean like `public static void, private void` etc.)).

**TLDR**

At the moment this won't let me get the `lookingToGetGearedUp` variable from `randomWorderer` and put it into the `onUpdate` public void. How do I do this while keeping everything in two separate methods or while being legible?

```
// note: this is only like half the class
    private void RandomWorderer() {
        List<String> lookingToGetGearedUp = Arrays.asList(
                "LOOKING TO GET GEARED UP?",
                "LOOKING FOR GEAR ON THE CHEAP?",
                "WANT A FAST AND RELIABLE SHOP?",
                "LOOKING FOR A SHOP WITH CHEAP PRICES",
                "HAVE YOU BEEN LOOKING FOR A SHOP WITH PAYPAL BUYER PROTECTION?",
                "WANT ITEMS FAST AND AT A CHEAP PRICE?",
                "SELLING A WIDE VARIETY OF PVP, BUILDING and RESOURCE SHULKERS",
                "\"amazing staff, quick service, will buy again! 10/10\"",
                "\"11/10 Above and beyond my expectations with excellent service, friendly deliverer and and infinite patience would definitely buy again\"",
                "\"9/10 very fast delivery cheap prices and good customer service\"",
                "\"30/10 got the items within 2hours fast asf\"",
                "\"10/10 staff was very patient and delivery was pretty fast (items were also very cheap)\"",
                "UBERSHULKER - THE BEST 2B2T STORE");
    }

    private Setting<Integer> delay = register(Settings.i("Delay", 30));

    public void onUpdate() {

        if (DiscordLink.equals(0)) {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(delay.getValue());
            } catch (InterruptedException r) {
                r.printStackTrace();
            }
            mc.player.sendChatMessage(">" + RandomString.getAlphaNumericString() + " " + lookingToGetGearedUp[r.nextInt(lookingToGetGearedUp.length)] + " JOIN UBERSHULKER TODAY!: https://discord.gg/xjnS2e9");
        }
        else {
            ModuleManager.getModuleByName("AutoReply").enable();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay.getValue());
            } catch (InterruptedException r) {
                r.printStackTrace();
            }

            mc.player.sendChatMessage(">" + RandomString.getAlphaNumericString() + " " + lookingToGetGearedUp[r.nextInt(lookingToGetGearedUp.length)] + " JOIN UBERSHULKER TODAY! To Recieve an Invite /msg " + mc.player.getName() + " request! and wait a moment!"
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when you can do, is return the `lookingToGetGearedUp` from the method. So, the method is no longer void (returns nothing), but `List<String>` (returns list of Strings)

Comment: Have your method return a `List<String>` instead of `void` and return the list instead of assigning it to a local variable that will be discarded as soon as the method is done running. Then just work with that return value.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also put the `lookingToGetGearedUp` not in the method, but in the class (so, remove the method, but keep the variable, in that case, it's available in the whole class), just like you did with the `delay` field. I understand, it takes a bit of time to get this stuff.

Comment: last thing: the "thingies", which indeed are methods, start in Java with a lower case, and classes with an upper case. Your RandomWorderer looks like a class (cause it's a noun), but it's actually a method, because of the `private void` thingie....